# Julian day from DateTime

Tags: php

Is there a better way of converting a DateTime object to a Julian day number than something like this:

```
$jd = GregorianToJD( $dt->format('n'), $dt->format('j'), $dt->format('Y') );
```

I'm a bit surprised there isn't either a function to do it directly or a format specifier to print it.  Am I missing something obvious?

**Edit:** Many of the (somewhat sarcastic) replies below seem to be assuming the Julian day number is somehow related to the long-obsolete Julian calendar.  It isn't.  The [Julian day number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) is one of the most common ways of numbering days from a fairly arbitrary epoch.  Its main use is in astronomy where it is the standard way of identifying a date.

Comment: sure, php needs *more* obscure fnctions

Comment: You are surprised there is no function that directly converts a Gregorian date to a calendar that people stopped using centuries ago?

Comment: I think this function is enough, php doesn't need more unnecessary functions for something that people stopped using centuries ago.

Comment: This is a very fair question, and what would achieve the OP's goal is not another PHP function, but a method within the DateTime class. GeorgianToJD takes primitive arguments, which I find more versatile. Splitting the date component by calling "format" 3 times isn't elegant but I'm afraid that's all you can do. (upvoted)

Comment: I think you're probably going about it the right way. There is an alternative function you can use for converting Timestamps to JD's, but that is I fear no neater. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unixtojd.php

Comment: Thanks, @d0ug7a5.  That's actually a lot better, as I can write `unixtojd( $dt->getTimestamp() )` which is shorter, but more importantly avoids the potential for confusion with the crazy ordering of the arguments to [GregorianToJD](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php).

Comment: Hey mate, no problem. It's definitely more succinct. :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
// $dt = new DateTime();
$jd = unixtojd( $dt->getTimestamp());
```

See more on [unixtojd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unixtojd.php) on PHP.net